# Required number of Euclidean Algorithm iterations for k, k+1

Tags: proof-verification, euclidean-algorithm

**Problem 1:** Let k>3 be an odd number. Perform the Euclidean Algorithm on 2k and k+1. How many divisions will be required? Explain.

**Problem 2:** Let k>3 be an even number. Perform the Euclidean Algorithm on 2k and k+1. How many divisions will be required? Explain.

**My proposed solutions:**

*Problem 1: k is odd*

Divide through until the remainder becomes 2. Then, for the next (and last division), it becomes a matter of forming an even number using 2.

2k = (1)(k-1) +(k-1)

k+1 = (1)(k-1) + 2

k-1 = 2n + 0, where n is a natural number, since k-1 is even

*Problem 2: k is even*

Divide through until the remainder becomes 2. Then use 2 to form an odd number, in the form of 2n+1. Since 2n+1 leaves a remainder that is a divisor of 2n, there is one last division.

2k = (1)(k+1) + (k-1)

k+1 = (k-1) + 2

k-1 = 2n + 1, where n is a natural number, since k-1 is odd

2n = (1)(2n) + 0

*Thoughts? Does this seem right? Should I be working towards definitive numbers, rather than inserting a natural number variable, n? Is there a more succinct explanation for these problems?*

Comment: Do you mean $2^k$ and $2^{k+1}$ ?

Comment: @Peter -- no. No exponent. Just 2k and 2k+1

Comment: In this case, we have $2k+1=1\cdot 2k+1$ and the second step already gives the result $1$. How did you get the $2$ ?

Comment: @Peter Oh, goodness. Let me edit. It should be k+1 and 2k, not 2k+1